# what the [n] in the make[n] means?

Tags: compilation, makefile, gnu-make

when I use a makefile I often see in my output make[1]... make[2] ...
for example :

```
make  all-recursive                        
make[1]: Entering directory `./splint-3.1.2'
Making all in src                                                                
make[2]: Entering directory `./src'
grep "FLG_" flags.def > Headers/flag_codes.gen                                       
make                                                                                 
make[3]: Entering directory `.splint-3.1.2/src'
```

what the [n] in the make[n] means ?

Comment: You might be able to answer your own question if you look at the output closely.  (Hint: Entering ...)

Comment: Hint no2 - recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are correct - `[n]` refers to the level of recursion.  At this point I wanted to point to the relevant documentation, but my scan through the [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) turned up nothing in this regard - perhaps I'm missing something.

Failing that, we can turn to the [source code](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/make/main.c?revision=1.257&root=make&view=markup).  `[n]` is the `int makelevel` variable in `main.c`.  This corresponds to the [`MAKELEVEL` automatic make variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#index-recursion_002c-level-of-410):

*As a special feature, the variable MAKELEVEL is changed when it is passed down from level to level. This variable's value is a string which is the depth of the level as a decimal number. The value is ‘0’ for the top-level make; ‘1’ for a sub-make, ‘2’ for a sub-sub-make, and so on. The incrementation happens when make sets up the environment for a recipe*

Comment: So if I understand correctly - this has nothing to do with recursion - the [n] increment when a make is calling another make (the same make or different one)... am I right ?

Comment: @yehudahs: Recursion is exactly that: something calling itself.

Comment: I know what recursion is. I am asking if the [n] will increment only on recursion (only when make call itself) or also in every make that calls another make...

Comment: @yehudahs - what's the difference between "make calling itself" and "make that calling another make"?  Are you talking about a different version of `make`?  or a different makefile?  or something else?  In the context of make/Makefiles, "recursion" usually means a recipe which invokes another make process, usually in another directory/different Makefile. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html#Recursion